# There are no review queues available to me but showing red dot

Tags: bug

I have noticed something strange today. There is a notification dot (red) appeared with my review queues icon. But showing nothing when I clicked on it.

[image]

[image]

The notification icon did not fade away even reading the message.

**NOTE**: I'm banned from review for two days. But if there are not review queues available, why does it show the notification icon?

Comment: There is a technical / performance reason for that dot showing: the indicator is deterrmined site-wide, not per user. Only once you click the dropdown, an extra call is made to figure out review queue states, at which point they find out you're banned. That call to determine the review queue state is expensive which is why it isn't run on each page load. So the trade-off is: poor perfomance for everyone or a sub-optimal UX for review-banned users. You pick.

Comment: @rene do those who don't have the privilege get the notification?

Comment: @Matthew nope, the whole UI element isn't rendered.

Comment: @rene: I'm confused. I understand why the queue state is expensive to retrieve, but isn't the banned-state for user inexpensive to retrieve? I can live with the state of being banned for something I did, but I think it is very distracting to have that red dot around when I can't do anything about it.

Comment: @benc when you open that dropdown and that server call is made that hits the database anyway I think we can live with an extra few milliseconds to determine that "no review queues available" is due to being banned. This question is about the red dot and for that it doesn't matter what is expensive or not as it already is determined that per user querying of that state, banned or not, is too expensive. That is not due to the state for one user, but due to having to do that for all users, on each every page view.